# scrolling background-position on responsive div - weird behavior

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with trying to scroll the background-position of a div to simulate a wheel animation (like a slot machine for instance), thing is - padding-bottom seems to get it stuck if over 48%. can you figure out why this happens?

in short- 
I'd like to know why this works (change background-position Y value)

```
<style>
body, html {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.wheel { 
    background: url(http://placehold.it/750x360) center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40%; /*Scrolls, no issue here*/
    height: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: 0px 2400%;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
</style>

<div class="wheel"></div>
```

And this doesn't -

```
<style>
body, html {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.wheel { 
    background: url(http://placehold.it/750x360) center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 48%; /*Stuck*/
    height: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: 0px 2400%;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
</style>

<div class="wheel"></div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the exact problem?

Comment: sure - 
http://jsfiddle.net/rbym475k/1/ - working version
http://jsfiddle.net/rbym475k/2/ - dead version

also - please note that the issue is when changing the background-position value in runtime (animating) that's what's stuck.

Comment: Yeah but is it possible you can add the scrolling effect so i can actually see when/what is going wrong?

Comment: sure- 
http://jsfiddle.net/rbym475k/5 - works
http://jsfiddle.net/rbym475k/6/ - doesn't work

Comment: after removing background-size: cover its working fine is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/rbym475k/7/

Comment: Not quite because it needs to maintain aspect ratio while being responsive :)

Comment: the thing is - 48% is exactly the aspect ratio of the image (360 is 48% of 750). the closer you get to that aspect ratio using padding-bottom - the less the background move when changing background-position, and at 48% it stops moving at all. there's some mathematical issue here.

Comment: at me it stopped working around 390-400 px are you sure its the 360 height?

Comment: The image is definitely 360px high :)
Again - this seems to be a mathematical issue with the aspect-ratio being the same as padding-bottom value.